# Can I restore metadata when restoring a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb

When I restore a collection with the following command:

```
mongorestore --db mydb --drop --collection mycollection --batchSize=100 mycollection.bson
```

as the original collection is dropped, the indexes are lost. I can see that there is also a `mycollection.metadata.json` file which contains indexes of this collection, but I cannot find in the documentation how this file can be restored.

All I've found is how to restore an entire database, which restores all collections with metadata from a directory. However, I want to restore only a single collection. How do I do that?

Note: I am using mongo version 3.0.7

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do something specific to restore metadata.
mongorestore does this for you.
When you restore collection:

```
mongorestore --collection mycollection --db mydb  mycollection.bson
```

mongorestore checks directory where mycollection.bson exist for  mycollection.metadata.json file. Just keep metadata file in the same directory as collection.